# Wordpress 5.1.1 conflict with multiple-content-blocks

Tags: php, wordpress

When updating to wordpress 5.1.1 my site generated a 500 server error. The log told me:

```
[19-Mar-2019 10:08:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare has_block() (previously declared in /home/rideands/public_html/wp-includes/blocks.php:81) in /home/rideands/public_html/wp-content/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/assets/inc/template-tags.php on line 67
```

So it seems like it could be a conflict with code which is in a a no longer supported plugin, multiple-content-blocks.

The code in question that is in the new wordpress version is:

```
/**
 * Determine whether a $post or a string contains a specific block type.
 *
 * This test optimizes for performance rather than strict accuracy, detecting
 * the block type exists but not validating its structure. For strict accuracy,
 * you should use the block parser on post content.
 *
 * @since 5.0.0
 * @see parse_blocks()
 *
 * @param string                  $block_type Full Block type to look for.
 * @param int|string|WP_Post|null $post Optional. Post content, post ID, or post object. Defaults to global $post.
 * @return bool Whether the post content contains the specified block.
 */
function has_block( $block_type, $post = null ) {
if ( ! has_blocks( $post ) ) {
    return false;
}

if ( ! is_string( $post ) ) {
    $wp_post = get_post( $post );
    if ( $wp_post instanceof WP_Post ) {
        $post = $wp_post->post_content;
    }
}

return false !== strpos( $post, '<!-- wp:' . $block_type . ' ' );
}
```

And the code this is conflicting with in the multiple-content-blocks plugin is:

```
/**
 * Check if the block has content
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param array $args Optional. Additional arguments, see get_the_block for more information
 */
function has_block( $name, $args = array() ) {
if( 0 < strlen( get_the_block( $name, $args ) ) ) 
    return true;

return false;
}
```

Any ideas how I can get the code in the multiple-content-blocks formatted correctly to stop this server error being thrown up?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since Multiple Content Block is no longer supported, the best thing would be to install Advanced Custom Fields, which does the same job but better. If that's not an option, it's safe to overwrite the old plugin's code, since it will probably never be updated. FTP to wp-content/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/assets/inc/template-tags.php, find line 62:

```
function has_block( $name, $args = array() ) {
```

and replace with this:

```
function has_the_block( $name, $args = array() ) {
```

The function's name doesn't matter as long as it's not has_block. Reload your site and all should be fixed. But seriously now, change that plugin. It hasn't been updated in 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

The has_block function is part of WordPress core. A plugin cannot redefine this function because it already exists. The plugin will need to use a different name for it's fuction.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_block/